# One navigation menu for every page

Tags: html, css, pug

I switched from `Jade` to basic `HTML` and ran into the following problem:

How can I have one navigation menu for my whole website (in one file)?

In `Jade` I did the following:

I had my menu in `default.jade`:

```
body
    .header-site
        h1.page-title Christopher Kadé

    ul.nav-site
        li: a(href='/') About me
        li: a(href='/projects') Projects
        li: a(href='/contact') Contact

    .main-content
        block content
```

And would include `default.jade` in every other `.jade` file, and write its content in a `block content`. This way, I have my header and menu available throughout my website.

But I can't seem to figure out the equivalent method in good old plain `HTML`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to have the same navigation menu throughout your website, you could either use `php` or `javascript`. Using php-

```
<?php
include_once 'navigation.php';
?>
```

Using javascript

```
<div  id="navigation">
</div>

<script>
$("#navigation").load("navigation.html");
</script>
```

Comment: Understood, I am receiving at 404 error even though my file is located on the same repository as my current `.html` file. I have added a div in order to contain my navigation and am trying to load it as you have showed.

Comment: If it is located in the same repository you should not have any problem loading it. If you are using github..this sort of problem sometimes occur in github.

Comment: Not at all, all my html files are in the same folder and yet by doing the following: `$("#navigation").load("index.html");` I receive a 404 error.

Comment: you might be having an alias problem , try renaming your file index.html to something else and  run the code again. You could also try loading index.html directly in the browser and see whether it is able to find the file or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need a server side include (with a server side language) - HTML doesn't support this natively. Or if using jQuery:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#nycontent").load("header.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="mycontent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>

header.html
<h1>test</h1>
```

alternatively, with plain old JS:

```
<html>


<body>
<script src="myscript.js" />
</body>
</html>

document.write('\
\
    <h1>This is my include file</h1>\
\
');
```